# Why do not order asc correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have in Sql a column name like that:

SpecificationParagraph

1

2

3

4

5

...

179

With my program i insert between row 1 and 2 a new row. My column are now :
SpecificationParagraph

1

3

4

5

...

179

2

When i try to order asc like that:

```
SELECT        SpecificationParagraph
FROM            CP_Sequence
ORDER BY SpecificationParagraph
```

My column get that order:

1

10

100

101

102

...

99

I want to order form 1 to 180. My logical to my program in vb is: when I insert a new row like 2, replace current 2 from SpecificationParagraph and after increment +1 all following lines.

Comment: It seems that the field used to order is not numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change **datatype** of the field to **int**, tinyint or bigint

Answer (score 1):

You have probably created `SpecificationParagraph` field as a varchar or text, therefore the order by dorts it as text, not as a number. Change the data type to an integer type and the ordering will be fine.

Comment: Yes, this is problem, Thanks